# How to use msbuild to build a Visual Studio 2010 project with 2012 C++ runtime libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, windows-runtime

I'm trying to set up build jobs for a project that has a Visual Studio 2010 C++ project. I have two build jobs, one that should build with vs2010 runtime libraries and one that should build with vs2012 runtime libraries.

I know that the project can build on vs2012 because if I open it in Visual Studio 2012 it builds fine. The problem is that if I run `msbuild.exe myproject.vcxproj` it automatically detects that it is a vs2010 project and builds with the 2010 runtime libaries. I haven't found any way to override this so that it would instead use the vs2012 runtime libraries for the second job.

Is there anyway to force msbuild to build with a specific Visual Studio version?

Comment: Seems unlikely, high odds that the IDE also targets the 2010 runtime libraries.  The property that matters, override it with the /p argument for MSBuild, is PlatformToolset.

Comment: Thanks. Passing /p:PlatformToolset=v110 worked! If you add your comment as an answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "Solution Explorer" right-click on your project and select "properties".
In the "Property Pages" under "Configuration Properties">"General" select the Toolset you want to use from "Platform Toolset"
[image]

To find do this from command line you'll need to use something like `msbuild myproject.vcxproj /p:PlatformToolset=v110_xp /t:rebuild` See the bottom of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293607.aspx) page for more info.

Comment: Yes this would work, but this is a build job. I need automate this from a the command line or a batch script.